# WorldClim 2.0 Solar Radiation data

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, climate, solar-radiation

I am trying to get Solar Radiation data from WorldClim version 2.0 in R,
However, I am using the library raster in R  but it seems to not be possible to download this data. (since there is only functions for bioclimatic data, Temperature, altitude, and precipitation)

Does anyone know how to download this data from the website using R?

I have specific coordinates. And for my bioclimatic data I have used this code, which worked:

```
library(raster)
library(sp)

r <- getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=10) 
r <- r[[c(1,12)]]

names(r) <- c("Temp","Prec")

lats <- c(48.45435)
lons <- c(-2.04734)

coords <- data.frame(x=lons,y=lats)
points <- SpatialPoints(coords, proj4string = r@crs)
values <- extract(r,points)
df <- cbind.data.frame(coordinates(points),values)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

`getData()` only downloads tmean, tmin, tmax, prec, bio and alt from **WorldClim v1.4**. Check [lines 252 to 325](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/getData.R#L252-L325).

You can download files with `utils::download.file()` function using [WorlClim data URLs](http://worldclim.org/version2), but it will download a full file, not a specific tiles as `getData()` does.

Comment: Dear Aldo , thank you very much, indeed that was what I was fearing. Following the topic, using download.file, do you know how could I get the tiles and the data for my coordinates?

Comment: @MaravillasRuiz Data by tiles is only for [WorldClim 1.4](http://www.worldclim.org/tiles.php). I suppose in a future will be available version 2.0 by tile too

Comment: I have been able to extract the data with ArcGIS and R code, and it seems that I can extract tiles... I have values for my different coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(geodata)
R_solar <- worldclim_global("srad", 0.5, path=tempdir(), version="2.1")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).